# if $C$ is a collection of sets, and $C'$ is a superset of $C$, what is the relation between $C_\delta$ and $C'_\delta$? and

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been studying the title "Mathematical analysis for machine learning and data mining" (isbn: 9789813229686), and in definition 1.27, it makes a strange claim which I have thus far been unable to prove:
the very last part of the very last line is claiming delta(C') is a sub-collection of delta(C)
[image: screenshot]

I am extremely new to set theory, and I would be very grateful to know whether it is a typographical error, or otherwise know the way I can prove it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a typo. It should be $C_\delta\subseteq C_\delta'$. I.e. any intersection which can be formed using sets from $C$ can also be formed using sets from $C'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I started that title with such a trust in its author that I still can't believe I have not been wrong in suspecting this to be a typographical error.